# Why is my eslint not working and throwing error in my Next.js

Tags: next.js, eslint

Eslint is not working for my next.js application, it is throwing "**Failed to load plugin 'n' declared in '.eslintrc.json » eslint-config-standard': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-n**" just as the image down there

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ESLint is having difficulty finding a plugin named "n" based on your configuration in your.eslintrc.json file. As a result, there could be a typo or misconfiguration in your ESLint setup.